# How to fill a gap on the floor before laying vinyl

Tags: floor, vinyl-flooring

My bathroom has a ‘click lock’ laminate floor and I’m going to lay new vinyl over the top. Currently there are edging strips covering the gap between the laminate and the wall.

To fit the new vinyl this slightly raised edging will have to be removed leaving a small gap to the marine board below and the wall.
I’m told I should fill this gap to make it level with the laminate allowing the vinyl to sit flat, and not ‘sink’ at the edges.

I’ve been told a screed could do it or, a sealant of some kind.
Never done this before.

Please advise on what to use and how?

Danny

Comment: The proper way would be to remove the old laminate, and install new on the sub-floor. **Why are you not removing the old laminate flooring before installing the new?**  When installed properly there is a gap between the laminate and the wall and it is covered by the base trim molding. ( i am not familiar with the term "marine board".

Comment: If water gets under the vinly flooring the laminate floor is going to rot.

Comment: I'm assuming "marine board" is the plywood subfloor